# Android Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone got an example of how to use the Android Graph API?

I am stuck with the basics, like posting text to the wall on Facebook.

I'm using the Facebook SDK for Android. Here is what I have so far:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "picture caption");

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new RequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, "foo");
```

Nothing happens, and my Logcat says:

```
03-02 22:10:02.973: WARN/Bundle(1930): Key message expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
    03-02 22:10:02.983: WARN/Bundle(1930): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    03-02 22:10:02.983: WARN/Bundle(1930): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
    03-02 22:10:02.983: WARN/Bundle(1930):     at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
    03-02 22:10:02.983: WARN/Bundle(1930):     at com.facebook.android.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
    03-02 22:10:02.983: WARN/Bundle(1930):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:182)
    03-02 22:10:02.983: WARN/Bundle(1930):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
    03-02 22:10:02.983: WARN/Bundle(1930):     at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:253)
```

Comment: From your error message it looks like you are putting a String into the key for your params Bundle when for some reason it is expecting a byte array.  I couldn't tell you much else as I haven't implemented their API.

Comment: Yes. I have also tried with a byte array, but it still complains. I wish there was more information on how to implement this API. The only I've come across has been in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, token);   
params.putString("message", "graph api");       
mAsyncRunner.request("/me/feed", params,"POST", new SampleUploadListener(),null);
```

you can get access token by using

```
      token = mFacebook.getAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like :--
give description in bundle message and if u want to share some image from server u can provide link as i given below

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "description");
        params.putString("link","your image url" );

new GraphRequest( AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "me/feed",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "" + response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                        if (jsonObject != null) {
                            String postId = jsonObject.getString("id");
                            if (postId != null && !postId.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                hideProgressDialog();
                                Log.d("postId", "" + postId);
                            } else {
                                hideProgressDialog();
                                Utils.showToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.txt_try_again));
                            }
                        } else {
                            hideProgressDialog();
                            Utils.showToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.txt_try_again));
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).executeAsync();
```